# tcpdump is overlooking some snmp traffic

Tags: linux, tcpdump, snmp

I am sniffing for SNMP traffic to code a testcase for some network hardware.
Currently I start tcpdump like this:

```
tcpdump -i any -nn port snmp
```

I then send some SNMP traffic from the same host:

```
snmpget -v 3 -u public 192.168.2.4 1.3.6.1.4.1.3181.10.6.3.65.1.1.5.0
```

tcpdump does NOT print anything right now. I verified with tshark, that the packets are seen on the wire. However, if I repeat the snmpget command, it will print the traffic:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/martin_testframework/Frameworks/P2P $ sudo tcpdump -i any -nn port snmp
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 262144 bytes
15:30:13.033363 IP 192.168.2.5.39351 > 192.168.2.4.161:  F=r U= E=  C= GetRequest(14) 
15:30:13.034473 IP 192.168.2.4.161 > 192.168.2.5.39351:  F= U= E= 0x800x000x1F0x880x040x4D0x490x430x520x4F0x530x450x4E0x53 C= Report(31)  .1.3.6.1.6.3.15.1.1.4.0=2
15:30:13.034908 IP 192.168.2.5.39351 > 192.168.2.4.161:  F=r U=public E= 0x800x000x1F0x880x040x4D0x490x430x520x4F0x530x450x4E0x53 C= GetRequest(35)  .1.3.6.1.4.1.3181.10.6.3.65.1.1.5.0
15:30:13.036447 IP 192.168.2.4.161 > 192.168.2.5.39351:  F= U=public E= 0x800x000x1F0x880x040x4D0x490x430x520x4F0x530x450x4E0x53 C= GetResponse(35)  .1.3.6.1.4.1.3181.10.6.3.65.1.1.5.0=""
^C
4 packets captured
8 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

Please note that this is the same tcpdump process as above. If I had restarted tcpdump, it would not have printed anything. Basically, tcpdump seems to suppress the first few (four?) snmp packets it receives. After the first few packets, it works correctly.

How can I make tcpdump print all the packets without a "warmup phase". This test was done by hand and there were several seconds between the call to tcpdump and the call to snmpget. Tshark sees and prints all the traffic, but I cant use tshark as it is not available on the production system.

Comment: How do you know that the first few/four packets are missed? Have you tried running the snmpget command again with the 'warm' tcpdump active (before you `^C` it)? What does it capture? Is it really the first-few packets that are missed or are a specific kind of packets missed?

Comment: @nik: Yes, I tried that. And, as I said in the question, I concurrently run tshark and tshark prints those packets.

Comment: Ok, try to use a host filter (host `192.168.2.4`) instead of the SNMP protocol filter. Tcpdump does not usually drop frames, your output shows 0 kernel drops and I don't think you have sufficiently heavy traffic to miss frames at lower layers. The two lines above are interesting -- 4 captured out of 8 filtered. This means you have a capture-filter (SNMP) that is causing 4 other frames to be skipped. So, try the host filter (or a full wide filter for a short time and then filter from a captured pcap).